# How to draw circles with animated edges in iPhone / Open GL ES

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

Could someone provide me with a start on the best way to go about this? What I want is circles within circles (for theoretical purpose let's say 3 circles). Each cirlces edge should be animated to mimic the aurora borealis (northern lights). They should flow and have subtle color changes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Some general questions:

- Use Open GL Project Template or View Based With <strike>drawing</strike> Graphics?
- How would you create the flowing animation?
- How would you blend the colors?

Thanks, -s

Comment: OpenGL IS drawing, so the first question is nonsense.

Comment: You're right I meant to say (core) graphics, but thanks for your eloquence. Next time try a hammer, might feel a bit nicer.

Answer (score 0):

I read about using Particle Systems with OpenGL to get these kinds of effects.  In a chapter in [iPhone Advanced Projects](http://apress.com/book/view/9781430224037) the author gave an example that creates smoke and fire effects using particle systems ([source code provided](http://apress.com/book/downloadfile/4489)).

If you search for [iphone particle systems](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=iphone+particle+system+OR+generator&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) you can find lots more.